# Google Maps Javascript RefererNotAllowedMapError for blob urls

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I get HTML code from server api and create links like this:

```
const blob = new Blob([page], { type: "text/html" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Then create a iframe to show this page:

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = url;
```

But I got a RefererNotAllowedMapError,

```
Your site URL to be authorized: blob:http://xxx.example.com/****
```

I already added `*.example.com/*`, `blob:*.example.com/*` in `Website restrictions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the text in the error message, you need to add:

`blob:http://xxx.example.com/*`

<s>(or `blob:http://*.example.com/*`)</s>     doesn't work per OP

Comment: Added ```blob:http://xxx.example.com/*``` solved this problem.
Seems wildcard not supported with blob urls.